# GLSL ES syntax error: '(' parse error after main()

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm getting a parse error with my shaders only in GLSL-ES 2.0 (android), they compile and run well in the desktop. The error is the following:

```
SGR(12584): Vertex shader compilation failed.
SGR(12584): ERROR: 0:397: '(' : Syntax error:  syntax error
SGR(12584): ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
SGR(12584): Fragment shader compilation failed.
SGR(12584): ERROR: 0:211: '(' : Syntax error:  syntax error
SGR(12584): ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

The line where it crashes (in both vertex and fragment) is the line after the main() method. Here is the fragment shader:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// POSITION ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define nop() {}

varying vec4 v_position;
vec4 g_position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
#define pullPosition() (g_position = v_position)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// COLOR ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
varying vec4 v_color;
vec4 g_color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
#define pullColor() (g_color = v_color)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// NORMAL ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
varying vec3 v_normal;
vec3 g_normal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
#define pullNormal() (g_normal = v_normal)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// BINORMAL ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
varying vec3 v_binormal;
vec3 g_binormal = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
#define pullBinormal() (g_binormal = v_binormal)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// TANGENT ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
varying vec3 v_tangent;
vec3 g_tangent = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
#define pullTangent() (g_tangent = v_tangent)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////// TEXCOORD0 ATTRIBUTE - FRAGMENT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
vec2 g_texCoord0 = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
#define pullTexCoord0() (g_texCoord0 = v_texCoord0)

// Uniforms which are always available
uniform mat4 u_projViewTrans;

uniform mat4 u_worldTrans;

uniform vec4 u_cameraPosition;

uniform mat3 u_normalMatrix;

// Varyings computed in the vertex shader
varying float v_opacity;
varying float v_alphaTest;

// Other uniforms
#ifdef shininessFlag
uniform float u_shininess;
#else
const float u_shininess = 20.0;
#endif

#ifdef diffuseColorFlag
uniform vec4 u_diffuseColor;
#endif

#ifdef diffuseTextureFlag
uniform sampler2D u_diffuseTexture;
#endif

#ifdef specularColorFlag
uniform vec4 u_specularColor;
#endif

#ifdef specularTextureFlag
uniform sampler2D u_specularTexture;
#endif

#ifdef normalTextureFlag
uniform sampler2D u_normalTexture;
#endif

#ifdef emissiveTextureFlag
uniform sampler2D u_emissiveTexture;
#endif

#if defined(diffuseTextureFlag) || defined(specularTextureFlag)
#define textureFlag
#endif

#if defined(specularTextureFlag) || defined(specularColorFlag)
#define specularFlag
#endif

#if defined(specularFlag) || defined(fogFlag)
#define cameraPositionFlag
#endif

#if defined(ambientLightFlag) || defined(ambientCubemapFlag) || defined(sphericalHarmonicsFlag)
#define ambientFlag
#endif //ambientFlag

#ifdef shadowMapFlag
uniform sampler2D u_shadowTexture;
uniform float u_shadowPCFOffset;
varying vec3 v_shadowMapUv;
#define separateAmbientFlag

float getShadowness(vec2 offset)
    {
    const vec4 bitShifts = vec4(1.0, 1.0 / 255.0, 1.0 / 65025.0, 1.0 / 160581375.0);
    return step(v_shadowMapUv.z, dot(texture2D(u_shadowTexture, v_shadowMapUv.xy + offset), bitShifts)); //+(1.0/255.0));   
    }

float getShadow()
    {
    return (//getShadowness(vec2(0,0)) + 
        getShadowness(vec2(u_shadowPCFOffset, u_shadowPCFOffset)) +
        getShadowness(vec2(-u_shadowPCFOffset, u_shadowPCFOffset)) +
        getShadowness(vec2(u_shadowPCFOffset, -u_shadowPCFOffset)) +
        getShadowness(vec2(-u_shadowPCFOffset, -u_shadowPCFOffset))) * 0.25;
    }
#endif //shadowMapFlag

// AMBIENT LIGHT

varying vec3 v_ambientLight;
#define getAmbientLight() (v_ambientLight)

// COLOR DIFFUSE

#if defined(diffuseTextureFlag) && defined(diffuseColorFlag)
#define fetchColorDiffuseTD(texCoord, defaultValue) texture2D(u_diffuseTexture, texCoord) * u_diffuseColor
#elif defined(diffuseTextureFlag)
#define fetchColorDiffuseTD(texCoord, defaultValue) texture2D(u_diffuseTexture, texCoord)
#elif defined(diffuseColorFlag)
#define fetchColorDiffuseTD(texCoord, defaultValue) u_diffuseColor
#else
#define fetchColorDiffuseTD(texCoord, defaultValue) (defaultValue)
#endif // defined(diffuseTextureFlag) && defined(diffuseColorFlag)

#define fetchColorDiffuseD(defaultValue) fetchColorDiffuseTD(g_texCoord0, defaultValue)
#define fetchColorDiffuse() fetchColorDiffuseD(vec4(1.0))

#if defined(diffuseTextureFlag) || defined(diffuseColorFlag)
#define applyColorDiffuse(baseColor) ((baseColor) * fetchColorDiffuse())
#else
#define applyColorDiffuse(baseColor) (baseColor)
#endif // defined(diffuseTextureFlag) || defined(diffuseColorFlag)

// COLOR NIGHT

#if defined(emissiveTextureFlag)
#define fetchColorNightTD(texCoord, defaultValue) texture2D(u_emissiveTexture, texCoord)
#else
#define fetchColorNightTD(texCoord, defaultValue) (defaultValue)
#endif // defined(emissiveTextureFlag)

#define fetchColorNightD(defaultValue) fetchColorNightTD(g_texCoord0, defaultValue)
#define fetchColorNight() fetchColorNightD(vec4(0.0))

#if defined(emissiveTextureFlag)
#define applyColorNight() fetchColorNight()
#else
#define applyColorNight() vec4(0.0)
#endif // defined(emissiveTextureFlag)

// COLOR SPECULAR

#if defined(specularTextureFlag) && defined(specularColorFlag)
#define fetchColorSpecularTD(texCoord, defaultValue) (texture2D(u_specularTexture, texCoord).rgb * u_specularColor.rgb)
#elif defined(specularTextureFlag)
#define fetchColorSpecularTD(texCoord, defaultValue) texture2D(u_specularTexture, texCoord).rgb
#elif defined(specularColorFlag)
#define fetchColorSpecularTD(texCoord, defaultValue) u_specularColor.rgb
#else
#define fetchColorSpecularTD(texCoord, defaultValue) (defaultValue)
#endif // defined(specularTextureFlag) && defined(specularColorFlag)

#define fetchColorSpecularD(defaultValue) fetchColorSpecularTD(g_texCoord0, defaultValue)
#define fetchColorSpecular() fetchColorSpecularD(vec3(0.0))

#if defined(specularTextureFlag) || defined(specularColorFlag)
#define applyColorSpecular(intensity) ((intensity) * fetchColorSpecular())
#define addColorSpecular(baseColor, intensity)  ((baseColor) + applyColorSpecular(intensity))
#else
#define applyColorSpecular(intensity) (vec3(0.0))
#define addColorSpecular(baseColor, intensity)  (baseColor)
#endif // defined(specularTextureFlag) || defined(specularColorFlag)

varying vec3 v_lightDir;
varying vec3 v_lightCol;
varying vec3 v_viewDir;
#ifdef environmentCubemapFlag
varying vec3 v_reflect;
#endif

#ifdef environmentCubemapFlag
uniform samplerCube u_environmentCubemap;
#endif

#ifdef reflectionColorFlag
uniform vec4 u_reflectionColor;
#endif

#define saturate(x) clamp(x, 0.0, 1.0)

void main() {
    pullColor();
    pullTexCoord0();

    vec4 diffuse = applyColorDiffuse(g_color);
    vec4 night = applyColorNight();
    vec3 specular = fetchColorSpecular();
    vec3 ambient = getAmbientLight();

    #ifdef normalTextureFlag
    vec4 N = vec4(normalize(texture2D(u_normalTexture, g_texCoord0).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0), 1.0);
    #ifdef environmentCubemapFlag
        vec3 reflectDir = normalize(v_reflect + (vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0) - N.xyz));
    #endif // environmentCubemapFlag
    #else
    vec4 N = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    #ifdef environmentCubemapFlag
        vec3 reflectDir = normalize(v_reflect);
    #endif // environmentCubemapFlag
    #endif // normalTextureFlag

    // see http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_chapter05.html
    vec3 L = normalize(v_lightDir);
    vec3 V = normalize(v_viewDir);
    vec3 H = normalize(L + V);
    float NL = dot(N.xyz, L);
    float NH = max(0.0, dot(N.xyz, H));

    float specOpacity = 1.0; //(1.0 - diffuse.w);
    float spec = min(1.0, pow(NH, 10.0) * specOpacity);
    float selfShadow = saturate(4.0 * NL);

    #ifdef environmentCubemapFlag
    vec3 environment = textureCube(u_environmentCubemap, reflectDir).rgb;
    specular *= environment;
    #ifdef reflectionColorFlag
        diffuse.rgb = saturate(vec3(1.0) - u_reflectionColor.rgb) * diffuse.rgb + environment * u_reflectionColor.rgb;
    #endif // reflectionColorFlag
    #endif // environmentCubemapFlag

    #ifdef shadowMapFlag
    vec3 dayColor = (v_lightCol * diffuse.rgb) * NL * getShadow() + (ambient * diffuse.rgb) * (1.0 - NL);
    vec3 nightColor = (v_lightCol * night.rgb) * (0.7 - NL) * getShadow();
    gl_FragColor = vec4(dayColor + nightColor, diffuse.a * v_opacity);
    #else
    vec3 dayColor = (v_lightCol * diffuse.rgb) * NL
        + (ambient * diffuse.rgb) * (1.0 - NL);
    vec3 nightColor = (v_lightCol * night.rgb) * (0.7 - NL);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(dayColor + nightColor, diffuse.a * v_opacity);
    #endif // shadowMapFlag

    gl_FragColor.rgb += (selfShadow * spec) * specular;
}
```

I can't see anything bad with it. I've found quite a lot of `Syntax error: syntax error` posts but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You #defined `pullColor()` as `(g_color = v_color)`, so after the pre-processor is done, your code looks like this:

```
void main() {
    (g_color = v_color);
//...
```

So you are starting a line with parentheses, which is an error.

Comment: That certainly fixes the problem. Thanks a lot!